# About appendStringInfo in C - I do not know how it works

Tags: c, postgresql

I am trying to use `appendStringInfo` in PostgreSQL server code. In this case it should add a column name, but it appears empty.

When printing

```
elog (INFO, "value:%s", idxcd->varattnames[i]);
```

the corresponding value appears to me.

```
for (i = 0; i < idxcd->ncols; ++i)
{
    appendStringInfo( &cols, "attname=%s", (i>0?"OR":""), idxcd->varattnombres[i]);
    elog(INFO,"indice:%d", i);
    elog(INFO,"valor:%s", idxcd->varattnombres[i]);
    elog(INFO,"cols:%s", cols.data);
}/* foreach col in varattno*/
```

Comment: It is a function of the stringinfo.c library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a trivial error:

Your format string `"attname=%s"` has only a single placeholder (`%s`), but you supply two arguments. Only the first one will get used.

Perhaps you mean something like:

```
appendStringInfo(&cols,
                 "%s attname=%s",
                 (i>0 ? "OR" : ""),
                 idxcd->varattnombres[i]
);
```